# Where to find old Raspbian release?

Tags: raspbian

I need an old Raspbian release, precisely `rpi_35_v3_jessie8_kernel_4_1_12.img`. On the download page [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) I can only find the latest release.

Is there any way to get the old release mentioned above?

Comment: AFAIK there was never a release with 4.1.12

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can download the historical versions offered by the foundation [here](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/)

Comment: And lite http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/

Comment: you, sir, are a life saver. 100 thanks

Answer (score 15):

**Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit ARM (After May 2020)**
32-bit Lite images: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/
32-bit with desktop: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/
32-bit with desktop & recommended software: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_full_armhf/images/

**Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit ARM (After May 2020)**
64-bit Lite images: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/
64-bit with desktop: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

**Raspbian ARM (Before May 2020)**
32-bit Lite images: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/
32-bit with desktop: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/
32-bit with desktop & recommended software: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full/images/

**Raspberry Pi Desktop for x86 processors (After June 2017)**
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/rpd_x86/images/

**PIXEL for x86 processors (Before June 2017)**
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/pixel_x86/images/

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can find all releases : https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/

You can find the images under **images** directory and they are compressed with zip.

**Raspberry Pi OS (32bit):** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/

**Raspberry Pi Lite OS (32bit):** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/

**Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) with recommended software:** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_full_armhf/

**Raspberry Pi OS (64bit):** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/

**Raspberry Pi Lite OS (64bit):** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/

**Raspbian OS:** https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/

**Ubuntu:** https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi